# Correct nginx rule for image files excluding subfolders

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I have this rule

```
location ~ ^/images/cars/(.*) {
    return 301 /images/car/regular/gallery/$1;
}
```

But I also want to redirect /images/car/*.jpg files. If I do this

```
location ~ ^/images/car/(.*) {
  return 301 /images/car/regular/exterior/$1;
}
```

then first rule is going recursively. So my question is how to exclude subfolders in this pattern `~ ^/images/car/(.*)` to avoid grabbing `/images/car/folder/folder/folder/123.jpg` but to take only `/images/car/imagefile.extension`

Comment: Not sure, but I think that `^/images/car/(.*)` will catch both 2 urls structures from the return 301. Perhaps try using a negative lookahead `^/images/car/(?!regular/(?:gallery|exterior))(.*)` See https://regex101.com/r/o5rkeo/1

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `^/images/car/(.*)` is too permissive and needs to be restricted to only the URIs that need to be redirected.

If you only wish to capture filenames, use `[^/]` which matches any character that isn't a `/`. Also, you need to use `$` to anchor to the end of the string.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/images/car/([^/]+)$ {
    return 301 /images/car/regular/exterior/$1;
}
```